# O que é Breadth First e Depth First?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, grafo, árvore

Quando estamos lidando com árvores e grafos encontramos esses termos. O que eles significam e por que eles são importantes no uso de estruturas de dados destes tipos e algoritmos que as manipulam? O que eu ganho ou perco quando ocorre um ou outro?

Comment: Existem dois artigos muito bons na Wikipedia: [Depth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) e [Breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). O que muda entre as duas abordagens é como a busca por um determinado valor na árvore é feito. Depth sendo uma consulta por profundidade, pegando uma "perna" da árvore e indo até o final. Breadth já seria pela largura da árvore (horizontal), consultando cada nó pai antes de ir aos nós filhos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Breadth first* e *depth first* são duas estratégias de busca semelhantes, porém distintas. Normalmente você encontra o termo completo: **BFS** ou **DFS**, onde o **S** da sigla significa *search*.

Seus significados são:

- *breadth first search*: busca pela largura primeiramente
- *depth first search*: busca pela profundidade primeiramente

> Sim, existem outras alternativas de buscas. O algoritmo de Djikstra, por exemplo, é uma *busca por prioridade primeiro*. Não vou entrar em detalhes sórdidos sobre outros tipos de busca em grafos, ficarei apenas com essa citação

---

Antes de entrar em mais detalhes, um ponto extremamente importante para se escolher qual algoritmo usar: em [problemas de decisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224811/64969). A busca em largura é garantida de encontrar solução (caso haja) em um problema RE, a busca em profundidade não; já a busca em profundidade acha muito mais rapidamente um problema na classe R (que é uma subclasse de RE).

> Definição em conjunto da classe R:
>
> [image: classe R, imagem cortesia do Anderson Carlos Woss]

A classe RE consiste de todos os problemas de decisão os quais existe uma máquina de Turing consegue definir, em tempo finito, se a resposta é "sim"; essa é a classe dos problemas tratáveis (para resposta "sim"). Nela, temos o [problema da parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969) e o problema de reconhecer se uma palavra pertence à linguagem de uma gramática irrestrita.

A classe co-RE, entretanto, é composta pelos problemas para os quais alguma máquina de Turing responderia "não" em um tempo finito; essa é a classe dos problemas tratáveis (parava resposta "não"). Um exemplo de problema co-RE é o problema do dominó usando os ladrilhos de Wang de forma periódica ([mais detalhes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile?wprov=sfti1)).

A classe R é composta pelos problemas que sempre se tem a resposta, seja ela "sim" ou "não", em um tempo finito (por isso que ela é a interseção entre RE e co-RE); essa é a classe dos problemas decidíveis. Um problema que está contido em R (e também contido em NP, um subconjunto muito pequeno e restrito de R) é o problema do caminho hamiltoniano. Sua versão de decisão é assim: dado um grafo `G` (com arestas ponderadas) e um número `k`, eu consigo passar por todos os vértices de `G` apenas uma única vez de modo que meu caminho tenha peso menor do que ou igual a `k`?

---

## O que é uma busca em um grafo?

Quando se trabalha com grafos (e, por consequência, com árvores), precisamos encontrar alguma condição. Existem diversos tipos de condições a serem encontradas, mas normalmente se dividem no seguinte:

- achar um vértice com determinada propriedade
- achar um caminho (conjunto de arestas) com alguma propriedade em particular
- achar uma única aresta com uma propriedade em particular

Muitos algoritmos partem de um único ponto, já outros partem de diversos pontos ([Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) parte de todos os vértices ao mesmo tempo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯).

Para os que partem de alguma origem única, ele precisa determinar como visitar os vértices vizinhos para, então, continuar a busca. Então, precisa ir para os vizinhos dos vizinhos e assim sucessivamente.

A busca em largura visita, por vez, todos os vértices de uma determinada profundidade ([relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/355117/64969)). Já a em profundidade, não, vai até o fim de um caminho para então tentar um caminho alternativo.

Um problema para visualizar isso é encontrar a saída em um labirinto.

> Dado um mapa, onde `.` significa espaço livre, `#` significa parede intransponível, `s` a saída e `i` a sua posição incial, é possível sair do labirinto?
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> #######
> #...#.#
> #.#...#
> #.###.#
> #.#s#.#
> #i....#
> #######
> ```

Primeiro: esse é um problema de grafo? Sim, ele é. Só que, aqui, não definimos explicitamente o conjunto de vértices e o conjunto de arestas. Temos, aqui, 19 vértices (todos os *tiles* com: `.` ou `i` ou `s`) e 18 arestas não direcionadas.

Então, precisamos encontrar um vértice com uma propriedade especial, partindo de uma origem definida. Abaixo, você confere a execução do algoritmo em profundidade levando em consideração o seguinte:

1. enquanto construo um caminho, não volto atrás (nós já visitados não serão revisitados em uma única descida)
2. se tiver mais de um caminho para seguir, primeiro vou pra esquerda, depois pra cima, depois pra direita, e por último pra baixo
3. se por acaso eu bater em um caminho que já foi percorrido, então isso significa que preciso fazer *backtrack* e posso abortar essa descida

Vou marcar pontos já visitados naquela descida em específico com um `X`. Quando for necessário fazer o *backtracking*, marcarei os pontos do antigo caminho com `B`. Quando chegar no alvo, marcarei com o sucesso com `Y`:

[image: percorrendo em profundidade]

Agora, vamos ver o problema sendo solucionado com uma busca em largura. Aqui, vamos evitar fazer qualquer espécie de caminhar por cima do caminho já percorrido (como fizemos na bisca em profundidade). Colocarei no canto inferior esquerdo da animação qual o nível de profundidade que estou expandindo:

[image: percorrendo em largura]

> Ser fôssemos usar outra busca, a [busca A*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239578/64969) atenderia e seria ainda melhor do que a busca em largura. Porém ela é uma [heurística](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357809/64969), não uma busca puramente sistemática.

Outro problema interessante sobre grafos é o problema da [ponte de zumbis](https://youtu.be/7yDmGnA8Hw0).

O problema consiste do seguinte enunciado:

> Um grupo de `N` pessoas liberou uma horda de zumbis no laboratório do alto das montanhas. Para escapar dessa horda, eles precisam atravessar uma ponte. Porém, tem um problema aqui: só tem uma única pessoa com lanterna e está escuro demais. Então, só é possível atravessar a ponte com uma pessoa segurando a lanterna e outra a seguindo, logo atrás. E tem outra coisa, cada pessoa possui um tempo diferente para atravessar a ponte, e, quando 2 pessoas atravessarem ao mesmo tempo, elas precisam andar no ritmo da pessoa mais lenta.
>
> Qual o menor tempo possível para atravessar todas as pessoas da ponte?
>
> A entrada será fornecida em duas linhas. Na primeira, temos um número `N` com a quantidade de pessoas. Na segunda linha, terão `N` números com o tempo (em minutos) que cada pessoa leva para atravessar a ponte.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> 4
> 1 2 5 10
> ```

Primeiro, esse problema é um problema de grafos? Bem, por incrível que pareça, é sim um problema de grafos... mas, como no outro problema, o grafo está *implícito*.

Vamos pegar o caso de exemplo: 4 pessoas, tempos 1, 2, 5 e 10. Podemos atravessar em 19 minutos se percorrermos o grafo de um desses jeitos:

[image: grafo bonitão do problema da ponte de zumbis]

Para esse caso em específico, tem uma heurística que define um limite superior:

1. a pessoa mais rápida sempre acompanha todas as outras pessoas
2. se ainda tiver alguém faltando atravessar, o mais rápido que volta a ponte sozinho

Isso garante que eu garanto que, em pelo menos `soma todos - menor + (quantidade - 1)*menor` minutos eu consigo atravessar a ponte (no exemplo em questão esse valor é `18 - 1 + (4-1)*1 = 17 + 3 = 20`). Com isso, eu posso fazer uma busca em profundidade e, se por acaso a minha busca tiver passado por um caminho com mais de 20 minutos, posso abortar essa descida. Então, nesse caso, uma busca em profundidade cai bem.

> A propósito, eu encontrei 17 minutos para a travessia de todos, e parece ser o melhor caso

Por último, gostaria de citar o [jogo Nim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nim) ([mais detalhes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Variations)). Esse jogo (na variação escolhida) consiste do seguinte:

> São 2 jogadores, Alice e Bob, que jogam alternadamente. Existe uma pilha com `n` palitos, sendo que cada jogador precisa remover 1, 2 ou 3 palitos em seu turno. O jogador que remover o último palito perde.
>
> Você deve determinar a estratégia vencedora para Alice, sendo que a entrada do problema consiste de um inteiro positivo `n` e qual é o jogador que iniciará a jogar.

Isso, novamente, é um grafo. Cada vértice do grafo consiste de 2 informações:

1. número de palitos na pilha
2. o turno de quem deve remover os palitos

Isso gera um grafo direcionado acíclico bipartido, cujo tamanho é limitado apenas pelo `n` máximo; como nada foi descrito a respeito de `n` além de ser inteiro e positivo, esse grafo tem potencial de ser infinito.

Assim, temos os seguintes vértices que definem vitória:

- `1, Alice`; como Alice precisa tirar pelo menos um palito, e só tem 1 palito a ser removido, então Bob é o vencedor
- `1, Bob`; análogo ao anterior, com Alice sendo a vencedora

Então, como descobrir a estratégia vencedora? Fazendo um conjunto de buscas por profundidade. Se o vértice representar o turno da Alice, então basta que uma das arestas possíveis retorne vitória para a Alice; caso o turno seja do Bob, *todas as arestas possíveis* precisam retornar vitória para Alice para que seja uma estratégia vencedora. A vantagem de se usar busca em profundidade é que podemos usar [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/64969): se eu descobrir que `k, J` é vitória garantida para Alice, então temos que, se por acaso eu encontrar novamente `k, J`, eu já sei a resposta dessa situação e, então, não preciso navegar por ele novamente.

Sabemos que `1, Bob` é vitória garantida para Alice. E o vértice `5, Bob`? Bem, daqui temos 3 possibilidades: `4, Alice`, `3, Alice` e `2, Alice`. Se, por acaso, todas essas opções resultarem em vitória garantida para Alice, então `5, Bob` é vitória para Alice.

Vamos para `2, Alice` primeiro. Uma alternativa é retirar 2 palitos, ocasionando na derrota da Alice. Porém, tem outra alternativa: retirar 1 palito. Ao retirar um palito, vamos para o vértice `1, Bob`, portanto Alice é vencedora.

Agora, em `3, Alice`. Temos 3 alternativas: `1, Bob`, `2, Bob` e `3, Bob`. `2, Bob` e `3, Bob` não geram vitória garantida para Alice, porém `1, Bob` gera. Então, `3, Alice` também é vitória.

Finalmente, temos `4, Alice`. Daqui, as alternativas são: `3, Bob`, `2, Bob` e `1, Bob`. Já achamos na navegação anterior que `3, Bob` e `2, Bob` podem gerar vitória para Bob, mas `1, Bob` gera vitória para Alice.

Portanto, como `2, Alice`, `3, Alice` e `4, Alice` garantem vitória para Alice, `5, Bob` também garante. E `6, Alice`? Bem, de `6, Alice` podemos ir para `5, Bob`, que garante a vitória. E `6, Bob`? De `6, Bob` caímos  em `5, Alice`, `4, Alice` (já provado Alce ganhadora) e `3, Alice` (já provado Alice ganhadora). Então, de `5, Alice` podemos garantir vitória de Alice?

Para isso, devemos ver `4, Bob`, `3, Bob` (já provado que Bob pode ganhar) e `2, Bob` (já provado que Bob pode ganhar). De `4, Bob` podemos ir para `1, Alice`, que garante vitória ao Bob. Portanto, em `6, Bob` Bob pode ganhar.

E `7, Alice`? Bem, de `7, Alice` podemos ir para `5, Bob`, que é vitória garantida para Alice. E assim podemos seguir para qualquer altura, usando a busca em profundidade memoizando os resultados.

A busca em largura, entretanto, não favoreceria no caso da memoização. Ele adicionaria na fila de vértices a serem visitados o mesmo vértice diversas vezes, aumentando a carga de memória máxima. Sem falar que, para pegar *todas as jogadas de Bob* de um certo vértice `k,Bob`, a busca em largura não facilitará obter a resposta depois de terminar a navegação.

---

Para fazer uma busca em profundidade, diz-se que se usa uma pilha; já, para a busca em largura, diz-se que se usa uma fila. Só não falam quais são os objetos empilhados ou enfileirados.

No caso da busca em largura, se enfileiram os vértices propriamente ditos. Mais ou menos assim:

```
def busca_largura(origem, estrutura_auxiliar):
  fila = Fila()
  fila.push(origem)

  while not fila.empty():
    sendo_visitado = fila.pop()
    if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(sendo_visitado):
      estrutura_auxiliar.marcar_visitado(sendo_visitado)
      [fila.push(v) for v in sendo_visitado.vizinhos() if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(v)]
```

Já a busca em profundidade, apesar de se falar que se usa uma pilha, normalmente essa pilha é delegada para a chamada recursiva de funções:

```
def busca_profundidade(sendo_visitado, estrutura_auxiliar):
  estrutura_auxiliar.marcar_visitado(sendo_visitado)
  [busca_profundidade(v) for v in sendo_visitado.vizinhos() if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(v)]
```

Se você desejar implementar isso de maneira iterativa, bem, é possível. Uma implementação ingênua seria empilhar os vértices. É quase igual à busca em largura, só muda a estrutura de dados usada:

```
def busca_profundidade_iterativa_naive(origem, estrutura_auxiliar):
  pilha = Pilha()
  pilha.push(origem)

  while not pilha.empty():
    sendo_visitado = pilha.pop()
    if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(sendo_visitado):
      estrutura_auxiliar.marcar_visitado(sendo_visitado)
      [pilha.push(v) for v in sendo_visitado.vizinhos() if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(v)]
```

Porém, sendo sincero, nesse caso você está usando mais memória do que a função recursiva. Por isso que chamei essa solução de *ingênua*. A solução recursiva mantém na pilha o nó sendo visitado *e também* um indicador de qual o filho sendo visitado. Então, aqui eu empilharia um par de dados: o vértice e o índica do próximo filho a ser visitado. Começando do 0, sempre. Fica algo assim:

```
def busca_profundidade_iterativa(origem, estrutura_auxiliar):
  pilha = Pilha()
  pilha.push((origem, 0))

  while not pilha.empty():
    sendo_visitado, index_filho = pilha.pop()
    # index_filho == 0 indica a primeira vez que se vem nesse vértice

    pop_valido = False
    if index_filho == 0 and not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(sendo_visitado):
      estrutura_auxiliar.marcar_visitado(sendo_visitado)
      pop_valido = True
    if index_filho > 0:
      pop_valido = True

    if pop_valido:
      vizinhos = sendo_visitado.vizinhos()
      while index_filho < len(vizinhos):
        proximo_vizinho = vizinhos[index_filho]
        if not estrutura_auxiliar.ja_visitou(proximo_vizinho):
          pilha.push((sendo_visitado, index_filho + 1))
          pilha.push((proximo_vizinho, 0))
          break
        index_filho  += 1
```

#### Sobre o uso de recursos

Cada problema tem uma busca específica que se encaixa melhor. Entretanto, cabe aqui ressaltar alguns pontos:

1. busca em profundidade permite fazer memoização em alguns problemas (vide problema de Nim/ponte de zumbis)
2. o tamanho máximo da pilha da DFS é a profundidade do grafo
3. o tamanho máximo da fila da BFS é `O(|av|*n)`, onde `|av|` é a média de arestas por vértice e `n` é o nível de profundidade sendo investigado; portanto, em casos de grafos cheios (ou simplesmente não esparsos), BFS ocupa mais memória
   Em DAGs, um mesmo vértice pode pertencer a diversas profundidades do grafo; por exemplo, no labirinto, a saída tem 2 profundidades: 4 e 16; isso é um dos fatores que explodem o tamanho da fila em uma BFS
4. em grafos infinitos (mesmo DAGs), uma busca em profundidade pode não retornar a resposta, como em problemas RE
5. se a resposta estiver em um vértice de profundidade finita, mesmo que o grafo seja infinito, a busca em largura *sempre* encontrará a resposta quando estiver explorando a *menor* de suas profundidades

Normalmente, a escolha pela busca em largura ou profundidade depende do domínio do problema, inclusive tem alguns casos em que a escolha de uma busca pode gerar um melhor uso da memória ou permitir otimizações (como a memoização ou a existência de alguma heurística de corte).