# O que é tree depth e height?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, árvore

Fiz a pergunta [O que é Breadth First e Depth First?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354665/101). Talvez um assunto um pouco mais simples seria o que são a profundidade e altura de uma estrutura de árvore. E por que isto importa na estrutura de dados e afeta o algoritmo que cruza a árvore?

Comment: Profundidade de um nó é definida como a quantidade de arestas que ligam o nó em questão ao nó raiz.
A altura de uma árvore é a quantidade de arestas no caminho mais longo partindo do nó raiz até suas folhas.

A topologia da árvore pode favorecer um ou outro algoritmo. Maior altura com menos irmãos em cada nível ou ao contrário.
Uma árvores desbalanceada pode afetar negativamente o desempenho dos algoritmos de busca.

Comment: @anonimodê uma resposta.

Comment: Deixando claro que apesar de colaborar com o concurso, não sou candidato ao prêmio.

Answer (score 4):

Uma árvore tem **altura** ('height') e **diâmetro** o **largura** ('diameter' o 'width').

- **Altura** - O número de arestas no rumo entre o nodo raiz e o nó folha mais distante. A altura da árvore abaixo é 3. (As vezes pessoas aumentam 1 por contar os nívels da árvore em vez das arestas.)
- **Diâmetro** - O número de nodos no rumo mais longo na árvore. A árvore abaixo tem um deâmetro de 6.

Os nodos da árvore tem **altura** (height) e **profudidade** (depth).

- **Altura** - O número de arestas no rumo entre este nodo e o nó folha mais distante em baixo deste nodo. (A altura do nodo raiz é o mesmo que a altura da árvore.)
- **Profundidade** - O número de arestas no rumo entre este nodo e o nodo raiz.

[image: Árvore com alturas e profudidades.]

O nodo laranja sólido é o nodo raiz ('root node'), os nodos cinzentos são os nodos interiores ('inner nodes'), e os nodos com linhas laranjas são os nós folhas ('leaf nodes').

Achei a imagen nesta resposta a [What is the difference between tree depth and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height/2603707#2603707)