# Qual o motivo da aplicação do conceito LIFO (Last In, First Out)?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, ciência-da-computação

Existe uma vantagem na implementação do conceito LIFO (Last In, First Out) ou é só uma questão semântica para representar uma ordem na lógica do algoritmo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não acredito que a aplicação do conceito de estrutura `LIFO` (ou a variante semântica `FILO` - *First In, Last Out*) seja uma questão de *vantagem*, mas sim de *adequação* ao requisito de um dado processo.

Como exemplo, considere o processo de [transações aninhadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_transaction) de um banco de dados. Certos comportamentos são esperados:

- Alterações dos dados só serão disponibilizadas quando uma transação sofrer confirmação (via [commit](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit));
- Transações subsequentes definem um escopo próprio, onde a transação-parente só terá acesso aos dados alterados na transação-filha quando esta for confirmada.

Agora imagine uma situação onde uma transação `T1` é iniciada, seguida de uma nova transação `T2`. A estrutura de aninhamento pode ser descrita como uma fila LIFO, onde `T2` foi o último membro a ser enfileirado.

Caso a confirmação da transação `T1` seja requerida pelo usuário o banco de dados pode decidir entre duas opções:

- Informar que a ação não é possível devido a outras transações pendentes (simplesmente verificando se `T1` está no topo da pilha), ou
- Realizar a confirmação de todas as transações listadas na estrutura LIFO, começando pelo último membro adicionado (`T2`).

Answer (score 12):

A pura aplicação desse conceito de UEPS (Último a Entrar, Primeiro a Sair) não traz uma vantagem óbvia inerente. A sua aplicação de uma forma específica pode ser bem vantajosa. O conceito em si é amplo demais para indicar uma vantagem.

O LIFO é quase sinônimo de pilha (*stack*) quando falamos de computação. Parte da vantagem de ter uma pilha já foi respondida em [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). E há uma outra resposta sobre pilha que ajuda entender: [Como funciona e se usa o Stack em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8972/101).

Sem uma forma de pilha pura pode não ter tanta vantagem assim. É possível implementar o LIFO como uma lista ligada, por exemplo, e assim fica bem ruim e não traz vantagens claras do ponto de vista de computação em geral.

É possível aplicar o LIFO em algo porque a semântica do problema exige isso, mas aí não podemos falar em vantagem computacionais, é um requisito do problema.

Para a computação a pilha geral ou a pilha de chamadas/alocação de memória local são os maiores exemplos do uso do conceito, mas o ganho se dá mesmo porque é uma pilha.

Então a pilha é vantajosa porque não tem que que manter nada sofisticado onde começa e acaba a coleção de dados, não é difícil percorrê-la, e principalmente é barato incluir e excluir novos elementos na coleção. Como só pode adicionar no topo da pilha (*last in*) não tem maiores processamentos necessários, desde que tenha espaço disponível, e como só pode remover o que está no topo da pilha (*first out*) é só mudar o que é o topo da pilha sem nenhum processamento extra, pegando o dado que está ali fácil e sempre de forma direta (O(1)).

Já a aplicação de pilhas, além dos domínios específicos que precisam da semântica específica que o que entra por último é o primeiro a sair (menores valores próximos ou o vizinho mais próximo, histórico de ações para fazer *rollback*), em computação tem muita aplicação, por exemplo [*backtrackings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138705/101) diversos (em geral analisando dados aninhados), *parsing* em vários níveis e modalidades, gerenciamento *chunks* de *heap* livres (em alguma implementações) e alguns gerenciamentos de agendamento de processador, Depth-first search, e as já citadas no começo da pergunta, além da mais óbvia que é a recursão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Não vou entrar no mérito tradicional, que creio que as respostas do [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433652/64969) e [OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434618/64969) já respondem o núcleo da questão, mas vou entrar na real vantagem de se usar pilhas em algumas classes de problemas. Portanto, espere ver classes de complexidade nesta resposta e se, por acaso, o termo "classe de complexidade" não fizer sentido pra você, então essa resposta não acrescentará muito.

Em [problemas de decisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224811/64969), existem alguns problemas que é possível responder, em tempo **finito**, se a resposta para ele é **sim**. Em compensação, talvez não seja capaz de responder **não**. O exemplo mais típico desses problemas em que há resposta para **sim** porém talvez não haja resposta para *não* é o [problema da parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969). Esses problemas pertencem a classe `RE`. Todos os problemas dentro dessa classe podem ser resolvidos por uma [máquina de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158043/64969).

> O nome `RE` significa *recursivamente enumerável*

Em compensação, temos uma outra classe de problemas: aqueles que se responde **não** em tempo finito, porém não necessariamente se responde **sim** em tempo finito. Esses problemas pertencem a `co-RE`.

> O prefixo `co` significa "complemento", sendo o complemento entendido como sendo a operação de complemento da Teoria dos Conjuntos

E existem aqueles problemas que você consegue responder em tempo finito **sim** ou **não**. Esses problemas estão na interseção de `RE` e `co-RE`, a chamada classe `R`.

> O nome `R` significa *recursivo*

Enquanto que para problemas `RE` você necessita de uma máquina de Turing com plena capacidade, para problemas `R` você consegue resolução com uma máquina de Turing com uma fita de tamanho finito dependente da entrada.

> Tá, mas o que isso significa no final das contas?

Quando você está verificando para saber se é possível responder, você tem uma fita da máquina de Turing preenchida com a cabeça posicionada em um local arbitrário, e a máquina está em outro estado arbitrário. A partir daí, você tem uma quantidade finita de mudanças:

- os estados que a máquina de Turing pode assumir são definidos por um conjunto finito `S`
- os símbolos que a máquina de Turing pode preencher em uma célula da fita são limitados pelo conjunto finito Σ
- a máquina de Turing pode ir pra esquerda na fita ou ir pra direita na fita

  - existem alguns autores que falam de uma terceira possibilidade: da máquina de Turing continuar na mesma posição

Logo, o próximo estado está em uma quantidade finita de opções para se buscar. Se o problema for `R`, isso significa que existe uma profundidade máxima de estados (no grafo de alteração de estado da máquina/fita) que se percorre até encontrar um beco com a resposta **sim** ou **não**, o que implica que, se tiver uma resposta positiva, ela está em outro percurso. Lembre-se também que, por conta da máquina de Turing que resolve estes problemas tem um tamanho de fita limitado, isso significa que ela não pode ir continuamente à direita, pois um dia ela irá esbarrar no limite da fita e estará em estado inválido e um Kuegelblitz surgirá e o universo será engolido por um buraco negro formado pela gravidade de fotóns em espaço compacto.

Porém, num problema `RE`, talvez não seja possível indicar que um caminho chegou ao final do processamento. A máquina de Turing continuará a se deslocar para a direita sem nunca chegar numa conclusão se a resposta para aquele caminho é **não**.

Na estrutura de resolução desses problemas, se você usar uma **pilha** (LIFO) para um problema `RE`, você pode entrar num poço infinito e jamais sairá de lá para investigar outro caminho. O jeito correto de se pesquisar por alguma resposta para problemas desta classe é usando uma **fila** (FIFO).

Em problemas de classe `R`, entretanto, usar uma **pilha** pode apresentar uma resposta mais rapidamente, pois você estará indo em profundidade no problema. Uma busca em largura exige verificar muitos caminhos intermediários que, talvez, não levem à resposta, sem falar que necessitam de uma memória sem limites.

Então, no final das contas:

- a pilha oferece menor capacidade de busca em termos de classes de problemas que se resolve com buscas
- a pilha oferece um limite menor de memória máxima usada para problemas que de fato ela consegue resolver
- potencialmente a pilha responderá mais rapidamente um **sim** para o seu problema

> Veja mais sobre [busca em largura x busca em profundidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354665/64969)

---

Um outro ponto que eu gostaria de ressaltar aqui, sobre [autômatos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/64969):

- autômatos de pilha conseguem responder problemas que podem ser representados por uma linguagem livre de contexto
- autômatos de fila são equivalentes em poder de resolução de problemas à máquinas de Turing

Answer (score 0):

Quanto ao assunto Estruturas de Dados, temos 2 as Pilhas e Filas, cada qual com seu comportamento e propósito.

Na Fila, temos o comportamento FIFO (First Input, First Output), onde o Primeiro Elemento a Entrar deve ser o Primeiro Elemento a Sair.

Então, na Fila (FIFO), temos dois pontos, um de Entrada e outro de Saída.

Na Pilha, temos o comportamento LIFO (Last Input, First Output), onde o Último Elemento a Entrar deve ser o Primeiro a Sair.

Então, na Pilha (LIFO), temos um único ponto de Entrada e Saída.

Comment: Parece que você está misturando os conceitos

Comment: Obrigado Favaretto, você estava certo! Acabei misturando os dois conceitos em minha explicação - agora já corrigido!

Comment: A confusão acabou, mas a resposta mão responde a pergunta, apenas repete o que já é conhecido.

Answer (score -1):

O uso da estrutura de dados **pilha** é uma das maneiras de calcular o resultado de uma expressão algébrica utilizando a notação polonesa inversa para representar a expressão. Na prática utilizamos a notação infixa, quando o operador aparece entre os operandos aos quais se aplica, acrescido do uso de parênteses para definir a ordem de cálculo, o que não é nada prático para o uso em computadores. Na notação polonesa a ordem operandos - operador é alterada para a notação pós-fixada e os parênteses são eliminados, vide algoritmo shunting-yard

Answer (score -3):

Não existem vantagens, depende da necessidade de cada aplicação.

Um exemplo de uso de LIFO são funções recursivas, onde você precisa retornar as chamadas na ordem inversa, da última para a primeira.

Já em uma fila de integração de dados com uma Web API você precisa que a ordem de envio seja do mais antigo para o mais recente, ou seja, uma FILO.

Comment: O que essa resposta difere das outras já existentes aqui? Não estou vendo nenhuma informação a mais em comparação às demais que já existiam antes

Comment: Apenas um exemplo mais simplificado, não gosta é só pular.

Comment: a propósito, o conceito de LIFO e FILO são equivalentes. Uma fila é FIFO. E uma API web não _precisa_ retornar em ordem crescente de datas, apesar de isso ser conveniente para muitas aplicações